# Compute depth without using any macro

Tags: macros, catcodes

For a library robust-externalize, write in a new file something like:

```
\newsavebox\boxRobExt%
\savebox{\boxRobExt}{%
  my content
}%
\usebox{\boxRobExt}%
% some code to write `\the\dp\boxRobExt` into an auxiliary file
```

in order to measure the depth of `my content`. This works nicely, but since `my content` is in a macro, it will tokenize it and make commands like tikz matrices to fail. Therefore, I need to use `ampersand replacement` which might not be really practical.

Is there a solution to measure the depth of a content without this issue? Importantly: I want the code to be as generic as possible, notably if it makes it work for tikz but break other stuff, it is not great (but might still be better than nothing).

MWE:

```
\documentclass[,margin=30cm]{standalone}
 \usepackage {tikz}
% most packages must be loaded before hyperref
% so we typically want to load hyperref here

% some packages must be loaded after hyperref

\begin{document}%
%% We save the height/depth of the content by using a savebox:
\newwrite\writeRobExt%
\immediate\openout\writeRobExt=\jobname-out.tex%
%
\newsavebox\boxRobExt%
\savebox{\boxRobExt}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [matrix,fill=red!20,draw=blue,very thick] (my matrix) at (2,1)
    {
      \draw (0,0)   circle (4mm); & \node[rotate=10] {Hello};        \\
      \draw (0.2,0) circle (2mm); & \fill[red]   (0,0) circle (3mm); \\
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
}%
\usebox{\boxRobExt}%
\immediate\write\writeRobExt{%
  \string\def\string\robExtWidth{\the\wd\boxRobExt}%
  \string\def\string\robExtHeight{\the\ht\boxRobExt}%
  \string\def\string\robExtDepth{\the\dp\boxRobExt}%
}%
%

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\begin{lrbox}{\boxRobExt}<stuff with &>\end{lrbox}` should work or the low-level `\setbox\boxRobExt\hbox\bgroup< stuff with &>\egroup`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel great, it seems to work pefectly, feel free to write an answer

Comment: Is the TikZ diagram with the `&` user provided or generated? In the latter just can use `\pgfmatrixnextcell` and possibly `\pgfmatrixendrow` for ```\\``` to not have to think about these things.

Comment: It is user provided, so sadly this later option would not work.

Comment: So the problem is not to save the depth, but rather copying the tikzpicture code to a file?  You might look at packges like endfloat which already do that sort of thing.  If you use tikz externalize, you might look in your working directory for files create by tikz.

Comment: And the depth is needed to insert back the file in includegraphics

Comment: @JohnKormylo Tikz externalize is quite bad and has a number of issues and limitations, that's why I came up with https://github.com/leo-colisson/robust-externalize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use instead  `\begin{lrbox}{\boxRobExt}<stuff with &>\end{lrbox}`, thanks Qrrbrbirlbel!

Answer (score 2):

`\savebox`, `\usebox`, `lrbox` are LaTeX's macros. If you don't want to use macros then you can use TeX primitives directly. I.e. `\setbox` and `\box`.
An use `\box\boxRobExt` after `\write` because `\box` primitive empties the box in the TeX memory.

```
\begin{document}%
\newwrite\writeRobExt%
\immediate\openout\writeRobExt=\jobname-out.tex%

\newbox\boxRobExt
\setbox\boxRobExt=\hbox{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [matrix,fill=red!20,draw=blue,very thick] (my matrix) at (2,1)
    {
      \draw (0,0)   circle (4mm); & \node[rotate=10] {Hello};        \\
      \draw (0.2,0) circle (2mm); & \fill[red]   (0,0) circle (3mm); \\
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\immediate\write\writeRobExt{%
  \string\def\string\robExtWidth{\the\wd\boxRobExt}%
  \string\def\string\robExtHeight{\the\ht\boxRobExt}%
  \string\def\string\robExtDepth{\the\dp\boxRobExt}%
}%
\box\boxRobExt


\end{document}
```